# Beginners' question on p5js print() function

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have seen some closed posts on GitHub, and the occasional unsolved similar question on random returns, but I can get a good explanation as to why on a simple `print()` command of a defined object the object is being printed on the console seemingly in a loop:

[image]

I just started using p5js, and don't know javascript. So it may be where the commands are placed (`function setup()` or `function draw()`), which I am still unsure why they are defaulted on the editor start page, or else I need to specify that I want the result printed just once (?).

Comment: Because [`draw()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/draw) loops forever. If you just want it once, move the `print(c)` call into the `setup()` function.

Comment: @phentnil What if I want to take a look at the output of some function that is being called from within `draw()` to see exactly what it is doing?

Comment: If it's being called from within `draw()`, it will print each time unless you create some variable like `var printed = false`, then set it to `true` when printing and wrap it in an if statement: `if (!printed) {print(c);printed = true;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `draw()` runs on a loop. Behind the scenes, the [p5js](/questions/tagged/p5js) library is using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to call `draw()`.

You could move the `print` statement to be within the `setup()` function, which only runs once at the start of the script.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  c = createVector(0,0);
  print(c.toString());
}

function draw() {
  //print(c.toString());
  background(220);
}
```

Or if you prefer, you can set up a conditional print block as follows:

```js
var printed = false;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  c = createVector(0,0);
  //print(c.toString());
}

function draw() {
  if (!printed) {
    print(c.toString());
    printed = true;
  }
  background(220);
}
```

**Note**: also consider using the [`toString`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/toString) method in the [`p5.Vector`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) object for cleaner output.

If you need to get output from a function being called from within the `draw()` function, you can apply the same principles as follows:

```js
var printed = false;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  c = createVector(0,0);
  print(c);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}

function beingCalledWithinDraw(){
  if (!printed) {
    print(c);
    printed = true;
  }
}
```

Runnable example:

```js
var printed = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  c = createVector(0, 0);
  //print(c.toString());
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  beingCalledWithinDraw();
}

function beingCalledWithinDraw() {
  if (!printed) {
    print(c.toString());
    printed = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```